# Test not passing for this java code

Tags: java

I'm writing code that whenever there is a ".xyz" in the string, it returns false, but if there's an xyz without the period it returns true.  The tests for most pass except for this one:

```
xyzThere("abc.xyzxyz")
```

Is there a way to fix this test so that it also passes?  My code is below.

```
public boolean xyzThere(String str) {
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 2; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) == '.') {
      if (str.substring(i+1, i+4).equals("xyz")) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    else if (str.substring(i, i+3).equals("xyz")) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean it should return `false` for any string containing ".xyz" unless is _also contains_ an "xyz" without the dot?

Comment: Just use regular expressions.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Regex is slower than substring and charAt, I think.

Comment: @luiges90, did you time it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use regular expression. If you worry about performance, create the pattern outside the method. Just write

```
private boolean xyzThere(String string) {
    return string.matches("xyz.*|.*[^.]xyz.*");
}
```

and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to return `false` for any `String` that contains ".xyz" **unless it also contains** "xyz".

You do this by first checking for ".xyz" - if it's not there then we're done.  If it is there then remove all ".xyz" and check for simply "xyz"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(hasXyz("abc"));
    System.out.println(hasXyz("abc.xyz"));
    System.out.println(hasXyz("abcxyz"));
    System.out.println(hasXyz("abc.xyzxyz"));

}

public static boolean hasXyz(final String in) {
    if(in.contains(".xyz")) {
        final String s = in.replaceAll("\\.xyz", "");
        return s.contains("xyz");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
true
true
```